# Fastest exact algorithm for MAXCUT

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, semidefinite-programming, max-cut, network-modeling

Is the algorithm introduced in the following paper still the fastest exact algorithm for general MAXCUT problems? TIA

- Ryan Williams, [A new algorithm for optimal $2$-constraint satisfaction and its implications](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2005.09.023), Theoretical Computer Science, Volume 348, Issues 2–3, 8 December 2005.

Comment: What does TIA stand for?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Probably “thanks in advance”.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted this; I think it's a good question. As far as I know, the answer is "yes." We sort of used $2^{\omega n/3}$ being optimal for solving MAX-CUT as a hardness assumption in work from a few years ago.

Comment: Yes, this is still the best known algorithm for the Max-CUT problem on graphs of unbounded average degree. For graphs of small average degree (say, <=10 or so), faster algorithms exist.

Comment: @AlexGolovnev, do you mind sharing the faster algorithm?

Comment: @OmarShehab, here're two examples, but I'm not sure if these are the best known algorithms for Max-CUT in sparse graphs: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637706000587    and   https://golovnev.org/papers/max2sat.pdf